# Symmetry Group of a Colored Cube

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning

What is the proper symmetry group of a cube in which three faces where none are opposite each other are painted yellow and the other faces are blue?

Any idea on where to start

Thank you

Comment: Try listing all the symmetries of the cube, and find the subgroup which keeps your yellow faces yellow and your blue faces blue. Btw, are you including reflections, or just rotations?

Answer (score 2):

For me it is easier to think of blue tetrahedron and a yellow tetrahedron glued together along one face. The symmetry group then is just the symmetry group of the tetrahedron, with one face mapped to itself: there is rotation of period 3 (on an axis perpendicular to the fixed face), and a flip (about a plane perpendicular to the fixed face). The dihedral group of triangle.